# "Ribbon.Read" has not been made available for this page or does not exist

Tags: ribbon, modal-dialog

I have created a link to open up a new page  in a model form.
I get this error but I dont know how to fix this

The Ribbon Tab with id: "Ribbon.Read" has not been made available for this page or does not exist. Use Ribbon.MakeTabAvailable().

Here is my code
Click here

JS
function openCreateTicketDialog(formUrl, title)
{
   var options = {
      url: formUrl,
      title: title,
      autoSize:true 
   };

my /MyFormTest.aspx page is a page I created 
   SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}

Any Ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Looks like I was using a WIKI page. When using a webpart page it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I was using a WIKI page. When using a webpart page it works fine.